# minify and combine all of sites plugin js and css files (with w3tc if possible)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, gruntjs, w3-total-cache

I am attempting to combine all of the css and js files that are generated by all of the plugins installed on my website. My site currently has W3 Total Cache installed on it and it advertises that it will combine all of my js a css files. When I go to css management (performance->minity->css file management) and even add one of my plugins css files, the sites styling then goes haywire for logged out users. Am I doing this right or is there another way.

I also thought of using grunt to compile all of the files into a plugin.css and plugin.js folders. The only issue I see with that is what if I decide to deactivate a plugin? I'm guessing all of the styles and js will not then automatically be removed from the plugin.css/plugin.js file.

If anyone has any applications I can use for this problem or even some good ol advice I would appreciate it.

Comment: seems like w3tc and maybe some other plugins may be my only option? https://css-tricks.com/taking-control-cssjs-wordpress-plugins-load/

Answer (score 0):

You could use node.packer to do this, but I would strongly recommend against merging all of the plug-in CSS files, as this will disrupt functionality and may interrupt any calls to the CSS files within the plugins. Plus whenever you updated any plugin, it would just create a new CSS file - so you'd just have to do it again.